# How to install lse_communication stacks?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found lse_communication is a useful serial port stacks.

Before, I use svn co to download and use it correctly.

But When I want to use the following command:

```
  sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-lse_communication
```

it says could not find that package.

How to use apt-get to install it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11033/how-to-install-lse_communication-stacks?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

LSE communication is currently not available as a Debian binary release.

You will have to install it manually via version control.

You can do this one of two ways, a rosinstall file, like this:

```
 - svn:
     uri: http://isr-uc-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/unstable/lse_sensor_network/
     local-name: lse-sensor-network
```

And then simply do a rosinstall

```
rosinstall <TARGET DIRECTORY> <ROS DIRECTORY> <ROSINSTALL FILE>
rosinstall ~/devel/ros /opt/ros/electric ~/Downloads/automow.rosinstall
```

And then source the generated file, for bash, this would be:

```
source ~/devel/ros/setup.bash
```

You can also add this to your `~/.bashrc` file.

Your other option is to actually check it out in your ROS directory:

```
cd /opt/ros/electric/stacks/
svn co http://isr-uc-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/unstable isr-uc-ros-pkg
rosmake -i lse_communication
```

You may have to perform some of these actions with sudo, and the -i flag to rosmake will mark the packages as built, so you won't have to rebuild them again (making it easier to work with user priviledges).

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-08-28**:
No, you can always update by navigating to the directory that you installed it to and running "rosinstall ."

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-28**:
If I use the first way to install,when that stack updated,whether the system will update it for me or not?